# image description on next/prev button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi a newbie here can someone help with this problem i'm having with the image decscription of my image gallery, when the thumbnail is clicked the description shows up but when using the next and previous button i can't get it to show `//image click

```
$('.pic img').on("click", function(){
  
    
    img_index = $(this).parent().index();
    $('.pic img').css('border', 'none');
    $(this).css('border','2px solid #4f4f4f');

    $('pic').css('marginLeft', '0')
    $(this).parent().css('marginLeft', '3px');
      
    image_address = $(this).attr('src');
    list = image_address.split('/', 4);
    name = list[3];

    $('#display img').fadeOut(150, function() {
        
        $('#display').html("<img class='display_img'  src='img/photography/" + name + "'> ");
     

            $('#display img').fadeOut(0);
            $('#display img').fadeIn(150);
           

    });
    $(".img_caption").children().remove();
    $(this).next('#caption').fadeIn().appendTo('.img_caption');
    $('#thumbs').hide();
    

});`
```

this is the previous button

```
// previous button

$('body').on('click', '#left', function(){

    if (img_index == 0) {

        img_index = $('.pic').last().index();
        
    }
    else{

        img_index = img_index - 1;

    }

    

    
    image_address = $('.pic').eq(img_index).find('img').attr('src');
    list = image_address.split('/', 4);
    name = list[3];

    $('#display img').fadeOut(150, function () {

        $('#display').html("<img class='display_img'  src='img/photography/" + name + "'> ");

        $('#display img').fadeOut(0);
        $('#display img').fadeIn(150);

    });

    $('#display').html("<img class='display_img'  src='img/photography/" + name + "'> ");

    $('.pic img').css('border', 'none');
    $('.pic').eq(img_index).find('img').css('border', '2px solid #4f4f4f');

    $('pic').css('marginLeft', '0')
    $('.pic').eq(img_index).css('marginLeft', '3px');
    

});
```

this is the next button
// next button

```
$('body').on('click', '#right', function () {

    var last_index =  $('.pic').last().index();

    if (img_index == last_index) {

        img_index = $('.pic').first().index();

    }
    else {

        img_index = img_index + 1;

    }




    image_address = $('.pic').eq(img_index).find('img').attr('src');
    list = image_address.split('/', 4);
    name = list[3];

    $('#display img').fadeOut(150, function () {

        $('#display').html("<img class='display_img'  src='img/photography/" + name + "'> ");

        $('#display img').fadeOut(0);
        $('#display img').fadeIn(150);

    });
    
    $('#display').html("<img class='display_img'  src='img/photography/" + name + "'> ");

    $('.pic img').css('border', 'none');
    $('.pic').eq(img_index).find('img').css('border', '2px solid #4f4f4f');

    $('pic').css('marginLeft', '0')
    $('.pic').eq(img_index).css('marginLeft', '3px');
    $(".img_caption").children().remove();
    

});

and this is the html
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
                    <div class="gallery">
                        <div id="thumbs">
                            <div class="pic item-1">
                                <img src="img/photography/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="" class="photo">
                                <div id="caption">This is image 1</div>
                            </div>
                             <div class="pic medium">
                                <img src="img/photography/thumbs/2.jpg" alt="" class="photo">
                                <div id="caption">This is image 2</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pic tall">
                                <img src="img/photography/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="" class="photo">
                                <div id="caption">This is image 3</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pic medium">
                                <img src="img/photography/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="" class="photo">
                                <div id="caption">This is image 4</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pic medium">
                                <img src="img/photography/thumbs/5.jpg" alt="" class="photo">
                                <div id="caption">This is image 5</div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We can't help what we can't see. Post everything you've tried to achieve your problem, and where exactly weren't you able to do what you needed done.

Comment: can you share some code? ( we cannot help if we dont see something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below code i have change `id` to `class` because you cannot have mutliple ids with same name .Then , to get the value of caption i have use  `$('.pic').eq(img_index).find("div.caption").html()` which will give us the description of that particular image only .

**Demo Code** :

```js
var img_index = 0;
$('body').on('click', '#left', function() {
  if (img_index == 0) {
    img_index = $('.pic').last().index();
  } else {
    img_index = img_index - 1;
  }
  image_address = $('.pic').eq(img_index).find('img').attr('src');
  list = image_address.split('/', 4);
  name = list[3];
  $('#display img').fadeOut(150, function() {
    //added direct src 
    $('#display').html("<img class='display_img'  src='" + image_address + "'> ");
    $('#display img').fadeOut(0);
    $('#display img').fadeIn(150);
  });


  $('.pic img').css('border', 'none');
  $('.pic').eq(img_index).find('img').css('border', '4px solid #18a6ed');

  $('pic').css('marginLeft', '0')
  $('.pic').eq(img_index).css('marginLeft', '5px');
  $(".img_caption").children().remove();
  //get text which is in caption div
  var text = $('.pic').eq(img_index).find("div.caption").html()
  //add that to img_caption
  $(".img_caption").html(text).fadeIn();

});

$('body').on('click', '#right', function() {
  var last_index = $('.pic').last().index();
  if (img_index == last_index) {
    img_index = $('.pic').first().index();
  } else {
    img_index = img_index + 1;
  }

  image_address = $('.pic').eq(img_index).find('img').attr('src');
  list = image_address.split('/', 4);
  name = list[3];

  $('#display img').fadeOut(150, function() {
    //directly add default image
    $('#display ').html("<img class='display_img'  src='" + image_address + "'> ");
    $('#display img').fadeOut(0);
    $('#display img').fadeIn(150);
  });

  $('.pic img').css('border', 'none');
  $('.pic').eq(img_index).find('img').css('border', '4px solid #18a6ed');
  $('pic').css('marginLeft', '0')
  $('.pic').eq(img_index).css('marginLeft', '5px');
  $(".img_caption").children().remove();
  //get text
  var text = $('.pic').eq(img_index).find("div.caption").html()
  //add to div
  $(".img_caption").html(text).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
}

.img_caption {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #cc216b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-wrapper">
  <div class="gallery">
    <div id="thumbs">
      <div class="pic item-1">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1f/65/30/1f65303066ef5e14cad11da3c6eeef0d.jpg" alt="" class="photo">
        <!--use class instead of id-->
        <div class="caption">This is image 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="pic medium">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e8/c7/c4/e8c7c4d4e14a9e3b21faf3d7b37c5b03.jpg" alt="" class="photo">
        <div class="caption">This is image 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="pic tall">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSrDI8z4T_iPTd3IzpxW_LPGeUPT3uVXwU4tA&usqp=CAU" alt="" class="photo">
        <div class="caption">This is image 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="pic medium">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTSkV92iBu84ig7ZueStpC8o1iX-8HEjcTXmw&usqp=CAU" alt="" class="photo">
        <div class="caption">This is image 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="pic medium">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcQEKkDxUl8wQXOgpZG7nRBfPL4Yu0O-ZTR_bw&usqp=CAU" alt="" class="photo">
        <div class="caption">This is image 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <h3> ----Here Image will be Shown --- </h3>

  <div id="display">
    <!--default start from 1-->
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1f/65/30/1f65303066ef5e14cad11da3c6eeef0d.jpg"> </div>
  <div class="img_caption">This is image 1</div>


  <button id="left">Prev</button>
  <button id="right">Next</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much i just couldn't figure out how to get the captions to show up on the buttons thanks so much